# Multiple values from a select and adding them up

Tags: jquery

```
<select name="" id="lensoptions">
  <optgroup label="SV Signature">
    <option value="100,80">Transitions</option>
    <option value="140,75">Anti-Glare</option>
    <option value="100,75">Polarized</option>
    <option value="84,42">Trivex</option>
    <option value="30,15">Scratch Coat</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<input type="text" id="beforeinsurance1">
<input type="text" id="afterinsurance1">
<br>
<input type="text" id="totalbefore">
<input type="text" id="totalafter">
```

**strong text**`I have an insurance form for work that I am creating, and on each option on the dropdown I have to have 2 values, one before insurance and one after insurance. I will have about 8 select boxes on the left and for each select I will have 2 input boxes to the right. I was wondering if there is a way using jquery to get two values from the select option and put them into input boxes located next to the select list.  Then total the column of boxes at the bottom to show the client total before insurance and total after insurance.  An example would be for eyeglasses, a scratch coat cost 30.00 before insurance and 15.00 after insurance.  So when I select the option the input boxes automatically fill with the right pricing and total at the bottom.  Thanks for any help!!!  I have been searching for days!!! Hope to use jquery in it. :-)

Comment: Share your code please. Preferably make a snippet replicating your issue.

Comment: Just use `.value()` on the select elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var price = function(e){
    // get prices from option value and split into before and after
    var prices = $(e.data.id).val().split(","),
        before = prices[0],
        after = prices[1]
    
    // set the prices in their respective places      
    $("#beforeinsurance" + e.data.sel).val(before)
    $("#afterinsurance" + e.data.sel).val(after)
    
    // call the total function on every change as well
    total()
}

var total = function(){
    // get the selected prices from their respective inputs
    var before1 = parseInt($("#beforeinsurance1").val(), 10),
        before2 = parseInt($("#beforeinsurance2").val(), 10),
        after1 = parseInt($("#afterinsurance1").val(), 10),
        after2 = parseInt($("#afterinsurance2").val(), 10),
        // calculate the totals
        before = before1 + before2,
        after = after1 + after2

    // check to make sure it's a real number before place in the total boxes
    // if this wasn't here, when only one is selected, it will display "NaN"
    if (!isNaN(before)) $("#totalbefore").val(before)
    if (!isNaN(after)) $("#totalafter").val(after)
}

// register event handlers on the change of your selects
// also passes in arguments to scope the 'price' function to the correct select and inputs
$("#lensoptions").on("change", {id: "#lensoptions", sel: 1}, price)
$("#frameoptions").on("change", {id: "#frameoptions", sel: 2}, price)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="lensoptions">
  <optgroup label="SV Signature">
    <option value="100,80">Transitions</option>
    <option value="140,75">Anti-Glare</option>
    <option value="100,75">Polarized</option>
    <option value="84,42">Trivex</option>
    <option value="30,15">Scratch Coat</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<div>
  Lenses Before Insurance - <input type="text" id="beforeinsurance1">
</div>
<div>
  Lenses After Insurance - <input type="text" id="afterinsurance1">
</div>
<hr>
<select name="" id="frameoptions">
  <optgroup label="SV Signature">
    <option value="120,75">Plastic</option>
    <option value="160,100">Metal</option>
    <option value="60,45">Wood</option>
    <option value="1000,100">Something Else</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<div>
  Frames Before Insurance - <input type="text" id="beforeinsurance2">
</div>
<div>
  Frames After Insurance - <input type="text" id="afterinsurance2">
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  Total Before Insurance - <input type="text" id="totalbefore">
</div>
<div>
  Total After Insurance - <input type="text" id="totalafter">
</div>
```

I'm guessing from your description and the names of your IDs that you will have multiple dropdowns and want the total to be calculated as well, so I added that in.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I will build the cells with the selections of options and post it here... Sorry for being so vague :-)  Your sample is almost exactly what I need..

Comment: @MikeLaFrance cool.  Let me know when you do and I will update my answer.

Comment: I hope this code update helps!  Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @MikeLaFrance Updated my answer.  Thank you for providing the code sample.  That helped clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you so much..that is awesome...this is great..I am so excited to build this form in html instead of excel

Comment: The copied code from above, straight into the Atom editor will not re-create what happens on this site when I run the code snippet. Not sure what I am doing wrong with just copy and paste into the editor to get it to work outside of this site.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Since it works here, it's not an issue with the code itself.  My first instinct is to make sure that your javascript is loading appropriately.  A common issue is loading the javascript before the DOM has rendered, thus when jQuery tries to attach events to elements, it can't find them and breaks.

Comment: Awesome. let me try that, I will let ya know what happens....If I copy the code straight to either Codepen or jsfiddle, should it work no problem?

Comment: Excellent, I got it re-created in Atom, now I can learn what you have done and hopefully figure out how to subtract some of the other parts I have on the form... Thank you so much Larz for taking the time to help :-)... btw, you were right about where I was putting the JS, I needed to put at bottom of body, and I had it in the <head> ...LOL